# What happened to the UI in IdentityServer4?

Tags: identityserver3, identityserver4

IdentityServer3 provided a basic UI for login, logout and a few other work flows. I am learning IdentityServer4 and was a little surprised to see that they don't provide any UI components for these work flows. I am browsing some of the [IdentityServer4 documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/signin.html) and I keep seeing references to a UI Quickstart application [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI).
Does this mean that if I build an IdentityServer4 implementation I must do one of two things...

1) clone/copy the Quickstart UI from Github into my IdentityServer4 project.

2) create it all on my own. So this would include the Account, Consent, Grants and Home controllers and views.

Is my understanding of this correct?

Comment: Your understanding here is correct yes.  I suspect you will want to provide your own UI, but you can use the Quickstart project to get you up and running quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing with this for a few weeks I feel like I can answer this question to help other developers.

Yes, you will need to implement your own from scratch or use the Quickstart UI and modify it as needed. This came from the fact that in IdentityServer3 developers often needed a way to override the pre-created UI. I'd recommend others to follow the QuickstartUI as a guideline and cannibalize/modify the code to fit your specification. See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXdJ2HLAOdE)

Answer (score 3):

Official IdentityServer4 UI beta testing [started a few days ago](https://www.identityserver.com/). Be aware it is expected to become a commercial product.